# How can I access one value among some values

Tags: ios, nspredicate

```
{
"id"=12
"genres_en" = "thriller,movies,action";
}
{
"id"=13
"genres_en" = "thriller,horror";
}
```

Hi everyone , 
I have one json like this..I mean i have one content and all movie has their genre ..And i need to do one categorization ..For example I need to check which genre of movie is horror..Or which one is thriller..I m getting all value like this:

-->  "horror,movies"
But  how can i do the controllation  to check whether the genre of this movie includes horror or not..??what is your suggesstion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(int j=0;j< GenresArray.count; j++)
                {  
                    NSString *value=[[genre componentsSeparatedByString: @","]objectAtIndex:j];

                    if([value isEqualToString:@"movies"])
                    {
                        [genreMovies addObject:value];
                    }
                }
```

Thank you for your help guys ..Now i have my result:)

Comment: Be aware that this line `[genre componentsSeparatedByString: @","]` is going to give you the same result every time and yet you perform it `GenresArray.count` times. It's not a problem if the string is small , but it can get a performance problem if the string gets very long. It would be better to just get this array once before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
NSDictionary *dic = PARSE The JSON;

NSString *values = [dic objectForKey:"genres_en"];
NSString *firstValue = [[values componentsSeparatedByString:","] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: using this solution it would be necessary to run a `for-loop` to find @"horror"(or any other genre) there

Comment: Yes I did like this before:
NSDictionary *dic = PARSE The JSON;

NSString *values = [dic objectForKey:"genres_en"];
NSString *firstValue = [[values componentsSeparatedByString:","] objectAtIndex:0];

But the problem some array has 2 value some of them has 3 some of them has 1 value and it gives error? I cant access for example all genre of horror and do this categorization?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Xcode nearby, so the following code may contain an error(or two :) ).

Try it like that:

```
NSDictionary *yourDict = //your parsed json
NSString *genres = [yourDict objectForKey:@"genres_en"];
if ([genres rangeOfString:@"horror"].location != NSNotFound) {
  return YES;
} else {
  return NO;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @santa what exactly do you want? What do you get? Is your json parsed as it should?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to check if the string contains the substring you want . Like this:

```
NSString *typesString = [dic objectForKey:"genres_en"];
NSRange range = [typesString rangeOfString:@"horror"];
if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    //it contains the substring "horror"
}
```

Or , the better way would be to get the array of types.

```
NSArray *types = [[typesString componentsSeparatedByString:","];
```

Now you can store this array for each entry and whenever you want to check if it belongs to a certain gender , just loop through the types array ( of each entry ) and compare the strings.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!